# C# Visual Studio Unit Test, Mocking up a client IP address

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd, mocking

I am writing some unit tests and I'm getting an exception thrown from my real code when trying to do the following:

```
string IPaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName.ToString();
```

Is there a way to mock up an IP address without rewriting my code to accept IP address as a parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Basically you get around such issues by pushing the data into a class with (for example in this case) a "context" or "settings" class.

```
public interface IAppContext
{
  string GetIP();
}
```

You then have a prod implementation that does the real thing and a mock or fake in you tests.

```
public class AppContext : IAppConext
{
  public string GetIP()
  {
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName.ToString();
  }
}
```

The app context gets pushed into the class using the ip address...

Oh- and as far as I know there is no inbuilt mocking for any VS editions, you will need to check out one of the many - [Rhino mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx), [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)... there are many! Also see [typemock](http://site.typemock.com) but it takes a different approach.

PK  :-)

Comment: Yeah I know about dependency injection, I just wanted to avoid having to change my existing code :(

Comment: There is Type mock - http://site.typemock.com/ - but I have never used it, I have always had the time to change the code! ;-)