# How to fake ip address for ApiController?

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a web api by `System.Web.Http`. ​
In a function I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` to get request ip address.

But when I tried to test the controller, I don't know how to fake the ip address to controller.

```
var controller = new ApplicationMobileStateApiController();
controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
controller.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());
controller.RequestContext = mockContext;

return controller.Authorization(body);
```

How can I fake ip address to do this unit test of APIController?

Comment: Do this answer your question? [Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678821/c-sharp-visual-studio-unit-test-mocking-up-a-client-ip-address/2678863)

Comment: The problem starts with the tight coupling to `HttpContext.Current`. Review your design to remove/abstract that coupling.

Comment: Show the subject under test, especially where `HttpContext.Current` is accessed.

Comment: You do not fake the IP.  Instead you create a test server on LocalHost to process message.